# FUN == 'x' does not work, how to go around it in R

Tags: r, function, evaluation

I am trying to write a function that uses some other function `FUN` as an argument - in this case, I want to (among other things), alter what to do if I set `FUN = match0`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
f <- function(df, pair, FUN, ...){
  
  df1 <- df %>% 
    group_split()
  
  w <- df1 %>% 
    map(~ .x %>%
          nrow() %>%
          seq())
  
  
  x <- map2(w, df1, ~map(.x, mean, df = .y))
  y <- map(x, unlist)
  l <- map2(y, df1, ~map(.x, function(x, df = .y){
    if(deparse(substitute(FUN)) == 'match0'){
      out <- x
    } else{
     out <- df[x, pair]}
    return(out)
  }
  )) %>% unlist()
  
  df <- bind_rows(df1) %>% bind_cols(index = l)
  
  
  return(df)
}
```

If I run, for instance:

```
a <- data.frame(n = c(15,20,15,20,15,20)) %>% group_by(n)
x <- f(a, pair = 'pairs0', FUN = match0)
```

I get  `Column 'pairs0' doesn't exist.`

This would be the case if, in fact, the conditional statement evaluated to `FALSE`. How can I change this?

To be honest, I'm not quite sure to use `deparse`, `substitute` and the like, I've just tried to follow some other posts. FWIW, I thought it would work because if I test `deparse(substitute(match0)) == 'match0'`, I get `TRUE`.

Any help?

Comment: The second argument to the function is `df` that is used in the function as a data.frame (or matrix). The character string `'pairs0'` is not a symbol evaluating to a data.frame.

Comment: Anyway, I cannot reproduce the error, the output I'm getting from the call you posted is `[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10` as expected.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I will try to post a more realistic example

Comment: @RuiBarradas now I guess there is a reproducible error

Comment: Outside `map2` the function `f` argument `FUN` still has the name `'match0'` but *inside* it is named simply `'FUN'`. Include `cat("FUN1:", deparse(substitute(FUN)), "\n")` right before `map2` and the same (changing to `FUN2`) right before your `deparse(substitute(.))`.

Comment: Well, that's because you didn't name any column in your input dataframe `df` "pairs0"  It's not at all clear what you are expecting to be going on here

Comment: BTW, as a standard practice, you should tell us what packages `group_split` , `map` , and other non-base functions are exported from.  Otherwise we're fishing blind.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That is right, but the thing is I shouldn't reach this branch of the conditional. My question is why is ```deparse(substitute(FUN)) == 'match0'``` not evaluating to ```TRUE```

Comment: So did Rui B's advice fix the naming problem?  I might suggest simply starting at the top of your code with `isItMatch0 <-  deparse(substitute(FUN)) == 'match0'`  and using that logical value wherever desired further down the function.